# .gitignore not working right after git init

Tags: git

I have reading plenty of answers, but none of them works for me. Specifically:

I have a project where I want to ignore all `.csv` files. So, when I run `git init` the git hidden folder is created, I go in there, create the text file `.gitignore` and I write inside :

```
*.csv
```

However, when I run `git status` it doesn't work. I thought it was because when you create a file in windows, you need to choose an extension. So in my case the name of the file actually was `.gitignore.txt`, but thanks to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKWez.png) answer I was able to name it correctly. However, when I run `git status` still appear all `.csv` files. And no, I haven't added those files (because as I said at the begining, I just run `git init` and given my research, `git init` doesn't run a `git add` behind). Here is a photo of the `.git` folder:

[image]

And the git status output (some lines of it):

[image]
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.gitignore does not go into .git/, it goes in the top level directory with your normal files.

If you don't want to check in your ignore file (generally you should), you can instead use .git/info/exclude

[The ignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description) explain where Git gets its ignore information from. You can also put .gitignore files in subdirectories.

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory (up to the top-level of the working tree), with patterns in the higher level files being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore file. A project normally includes such .gitignore files in its repository, containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.

Comment: And the solution was so simple! You know that nowhere I read it says that you have to actually have to put the .gitignore file in the main folder and not inside .git? I have been more than one hour looking for this solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Chris Where Git gets its ignore information from is documented in the first page or so of the [gitignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description).

Answer (score 1):

There's several places you can put your `.gitignore` file to, but `.git/` folder is not one of them.

The most common way is to have one `.gitignore` file in your repository root. This works for you whole repository. You can also place `.gitignore` file in any subdirectory, and those will affect the subdirectory they are placed in.

Additionally, you can set an extra exclude file with git config `core.excludesFile`. Usually you would use this to set a global `.gitignore` that ignores for example temporary files created by your OS or tools of your choice.

See the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for more details.